# display product name in custom page in admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to display product name in the custom page in admin grid it displaying in the grid but I want to display in the custom page which will open on view click
[image]
[image]

```
<field name="customization_attachment">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">file</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Attachment</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customization_attachment</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: Share you code here. If you want display product information in new admin page and that will open on view action. So you need to pass a new controller action in on view then create a new controller and fetch the information whatever you want.

Comment: I have passed everything all other details are coming that user entered but now I want to display product name and product image i have add ss please see

Comment: Yeah got it and please add your code in which the edit form comes from

Comment: i have added a code

Comment: and full code is not coming in this comment

Comment: Hey, you'd probably fetching information from block file and that is where you gotta fetch these details and if you have product id then you can fetch everything out there.

Comment: yes i have stored productid in database but how can fetch product name and image through it